# Laravel base route errors "NotFoundHttpException"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm too newbie to Laravel...I have written this route to echo "Hello World", but It errors  `NotFoundHttpException`

This is my routes.php (no other code is in the file but the following):

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return "HELLO WORLD";   
});
```

I have also enable mode_rewrite, and also set AlloOverride to 'all' in apache module.

This is also the URL is use to access the page:

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/mostafa
```

Comment: What URL are u using in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost/laravel/public/mostafa

Comment: The route is `http://localhost/`.

Comment: `.get('/')` is the root route, so `http://localhost/` should show "HELLO WORLD".

Comment: I changed it to `"/mostafa"` but it does not work. By default it works, without appending any string to `"/"`, while I want to see it work with appended string such as `"/mostafa"`

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
php artisan serve
```

Use that URL to visit your website.

You will see that you get some output like:

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
```

When you have no clue what Artisan is take a look at this; 
http://laravel.com/docs/artisan

Navigate into your project directory with your command prompt and run there the serve command from above.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Well, use in your browser now: http://localhost:8000
When you change your route to: Route::get('mostafa', function(){..} 
you can visit : http://localhost:8000/mostafa

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the default .htaccess file located in public folder doesn't work in apache. Try altering the .htacess as mentioned [here](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls). Alternatively renaming your laravel project folder would work especially in XAMPP.

Comment: i have renamed my project to FW and also have replaced the content of the .htaccess in public folder to that of Laravel Website's suggestion but still it does not work. The same error persistently is thrown..

Comment: Try accessing the following url http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/mostafa. If the path works then it is a known issue especially involving xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Some other frameworks treat route definitions as relative to the project web root so a path defined as `/foo/bar` will match `http://example.com/additional/levels/laravel/public/foo/bar` and will work without changes even if you move the project tree somewhere else in your public web hierarchy. Laravel, however, considers routes as absolute paths so `/foo/bar` will only match `http://example.com/foo/bar`.

The simplest solution is probably to move your code into a separate virtual host and point its document root to `laravel/public/`. (In this case it seems that's actually the intended set-up.)

<sub>(I suppose there's a way to make the framework assume an implicit prefix but I've only been using Laravel for 10 minutes.)</sub>